# Same homology and distinct homotopy on torus

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory

I want to find a topological space $X$ such that $X$ and $T^2 = S^1 \times S^1$ have the same of homology and distinct homotopy, but I have no idea how to find it. Can you help me? Thank you very much.

Comment: I think it is a bit difficult to give a helpful hint without giving away the answer, but think about the relation of the wedge sum with homology for reasonable spaces and about the fundamental group of wedge sums of circles in order to build an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: What's the simplest possible way to build a space with the homology groups of $T^2$?  How could you put together simple pieces to end up with a connected space $X$ with $H_2(X)\cong\mathbb{Z}$ and $H_1(X)\cong\mathbb{Z}^2$?  (If you've learned a general method to construct a space with specified homology groups, you could see what that method gives you in this case.)